# Jquery Slimbox and AJAX Image Swapping Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox, livequery, slimbox

First I'll mention that I have browsed through countless questions and answers, many of which would logically seem to work.

I am having an issue with slimbox and AJAX.  I am performing a simple image swap and when I do so, slimbox will not work for the newly added image.

I tried many things from invoking Live Query (jquery addon) to simply trying to rebind or invoke slimbox again.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Maybe putting my exact scenario into context will help relate one of the solutions already out there to fix my problem.  I've not been able to incorporate them thus far.

**Step 1:** I have my php code generating my page with a main image, for which slimbox works great:

```
<div id="productMainImage" class="centeredContent back">
    <a href="images/large/redwhiteandyou_LRG.jpg" rel="lightbox-g" title="Red White and You"><img src="images/medium/redwhiteandyou_MED.jpg" alt="Red White and You" title=" Red White and You " width="250" height="167"><br><span class="imgLink">larger image</span></a>
</div>
```

**Step 2:** I have a set of attribute images created, where I am invoking my ajax code to do the image swap.  This does some processing and basically sets the innerhtml of #productMainImage as follows:

```
<div id="productMainImage" class="centeredContent back">
    <a id="Yellow" href="images/large/attributes/redwhiteandyou_yellow_LRG.jpg" rel="lightbox-g" title="Yellow"><img src="images/medium/attributes/redwhiteandyou_yellow_MED.jpg" alt="Yellow" title=" Yellow " width="250" height="167"><br><span class="imgLink">larger image</span></a>
</div>
```

The swap works fine and the image changes.  The big question is how I can make sure to link that image up with slimbox.

A couple of thing things I've tried are (not limited to!):

Inserting javascript in the code called by ajax to write out the html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').find("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({}, null, function(el) {
        return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    });
});
```

OR

```
$("a[rel^='lightbox']").livequery(function(){
    $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
    return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    }), function() {
        //remove slimbox? this is called when elements no longer match
    }
});
```

I have also tried inserting code in my page attempting similar things.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I continued to try to solve this and found what I was doing wrong.  A core misunderstanding in the flow of how AJAX was updating the page.  I plugged the slimbox call into the following function in the AJAX code and it works now!

```
function stateChanged() { 
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){    
    var product_color_image=xmlHttp.responseText;
    if(product_color_image!=''){
    document.getElementById('productMainImage').innerHTML = product_color_image;
    }
    $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({
      <?php require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG . DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'zen_lightbox/options.php'); ?>
    }, function(el){
      return [el.href, el.title /* + '<br /><a href="' + el.href + '">Download this image</a>'*/];
       }, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
          }), function() {
                //remove slimbox? this is called when elements no longer match
              }
    }
}
```

I need to work through a few of the finer details, but at least now my images are displaying with a lightbox after I've performed an AJAX swap on the main product image!